# Fixing 3 variables to find the influence of a 4th?

Tags: correlation

I have a set of data with 4 input variables and 1 result field (they're all numerical values). I want to determine the influence of variable #4 on the outcomes, so it makes sense to try to fix the other 3 inputs and the compare the results versus the value of var #4. I realize I'm probably using horrendous statistics terminology, but I was just looking for some quick help--and yes, this can be quick and dirty, it doesn't have to be professional level.

Answer (score 4):

Fit linear regression model:

$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+\beta_4X_4$

where $X_i$ are your input variables and $Y$ is the outcome. The interpretation of coefficient $\beta_4$ then is the size of change of Y if we change $X_4$ by one unit, holding other input variables constant.

Comment: +1.  Given that this is truly "quick and dirty," one might be inclined to emphasize that $\beta_4$ is the *average* marginal change in Y.  It could differ appreciably from the actual marginal changes.  This average will be meaningful only if the relationships among the independent variables and the dependent variable are reasonably linear.